# Checking if a user defined DateTime is between two times

Tags: c#, datetime, time, range, datetimepicker

So I have a dateTimePicker which is labeled as pickUpTime.

```
DateTime pickUpTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddHours(pickUpTimePicker.Value.Hour);
```

Which lets the user select a date and time and assigns it to pickUpTime.

I am trying to write a statement that will execute and add an extra charge if the pickUpTime is in between a range of times. Say 00:00 and 06:59 or 18:00 and 23:59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify the `TimeOfDay` of one `DateTime` is between two `TimeSpans`:

```
TimeSpan lowerTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan upperTime = new TimeSpan(6, 59, 0);
bool result = pickUpTime.TimeOfDay >= lowerTime
    && pickUpTime <= upperTime;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to what I was trying last night except when I tried to compare the pickUpTime to the lowerTime I left out pickUpTime.TimeOfDay and just tried pickUpTime.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of ticks

```
if (targetDt.Ticks > d1.Ticks && targetDt.Ticks < d2.Ticks)
{
    // targetDt is in between d1 and d2
}
```

where d1 and d2 are your specified times